# Python Add a New Line without \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this

```
    f = open(os.path.join(r"/path/to/file/{}.txt").format(userid), "w")
    f.write(str(points))
    f.write(str(level))
    f.write(str(prevtime))
    f.close()
```

I know about using `with open(blah) as f:` and prefer this but when I have this code, even if I write the file first and then change to append mode, without adding a +"\n" it doesn't add to a new line. The reason \n is a problem is that when I go to get the data using

```
    f = open(os.path.join(r"blah\{}.txt").format(userid), "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    points = float(lines[0])
```

I'll get an error telling me it can't interpret (for example: 500\n) as a float because it reads the \n. Any idea what I can do?

**EDIT**
I ended up fixing it by just not making it a float, but now that is giving me a ValueError Unconverted Data Remains. These issues are only happening due to the line in the txt file that should contain a date in the format of %H:%M

**EDIT 2019**
I see lots of people trying to search the same question. My problem actually ended up with me ignoring and having a very clear lack of understanding of types in Python.
To answer the question that I imagine many people are searching for when they view this, `\n` is Python's newline character. An alternative (if using `print()`) would to be to call `print()` exactly as shown with no data, resulting in a blank line.

Comment: Why are you using `os.path.join` without joining anything?

Comment: Why not use `rstrip` to get rid of the \n

Comment: It looks like you have some bug you don't understand, and you've wrongly blamed the use of `\n`. `\n` is fine; you have some other issue.

Comment: Do you want `\n`s in the file, or not?

Comment: `float("500\n")` should not fail.  Can you give us a complete, self-contained program that reproduces your error?

Comment: If you `print(repr(lines[0]))` what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have something like this

```
>>> f = open("test.txt", "w")
>>> f.write(str(4))
>>> f.write(str(20))
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> f.readlines()
['420']
```

But, you need to write newlines, so just do so

```
>>> f = open("test.txt", "w")
>>> f.write("{}\n".format(4))
>>> f.write("{}\n".format(20))
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> f.readlines()
['4\n', '20\n']
>>> f.close()
```

If you need no newline characters, try `read().splitlines()`

```
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> f.read().splitlines()
['4', '20']
```

**EDIT**

As far as the time value is concerned, here's an example.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time_str = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
>>> time_str
'18:26'
>>> datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 18, 26)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print without newlines, use below.
But without newlines, you might need to add some separator like space to separate your data

```
 >>> sys.stdout.write('hello world')
hello world>>>
```

With the newlines remain, you could use rstrip to strip off the newlines when reading out

```
lines = f.readlines()
points = float(lines[0].rstrip)
```

Alternatively, I prefer more pythonic way below

```
lines = f.read().splitlines()
points = float(lines[0])
```

Comment: Just learn that int or float function will works even the numeric string contains newline \n